# AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'close'

Tags: python, pyqt5, attributeerror

So, I am making an application using pyqt5
I want to close the window when I click a button, For that, I wrote this:

```
self.login.clicked.connect(self.closewin)
```

and the close fuction is:

```
def closewin(self):
        self.close()
```

and I am getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'close'
```

what should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect slots in `MainWindow.__init__()` not in `Ui_MainWindow.setupUi()`. `MainWindow` is window class (put `def closewin(self)` here), `Ui_MainWindow` is helper class.

```
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(self)
ui.login.clicked.connect(self.closewin)
```